# Multiplying to reverse digits

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, combinatorics

Today I noticed that $294$ is a multiple of $49$, which is the last two digits of $294$ reversed.

How many other numbers have this property? That is, **how many three-digit numbers have a factor which is given by taking the last two digits and reversing them?**

Notes:

- I don't know the answer to this question, but I imagine it must be doable in a relatively neat way without too much case-bashing. No programming answers, please.
- Leading zeros are not allowed. When I say "three-digit numbers" it excludes one- and two- digit numbers, and the two-digit factor shouldn't be a one-digit number.

Comment: The programming answer is actually rather fun, but unfortunately out of scope.

Comment: I know it says `no-computers` but I couldn't resist: (Python) `sorted(set([n if n%10!=0 and n%int(str(n)[:0:-1])==0 else 0 for n in range(100,1000)]))[1:]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are

> 10.

My process:

> Eliminate the possibilities with a zero in the 2nd or 3rd digit, as we can't have a 1-digit factor, and having a zero as the last digit of the factor would require the result also end in zero.
>  Eliminate those where the last two digits are the same.
>  Eliminate the numbers where the 2nd digit is even, and the last digit is odd, as the an odd number is never divisible by an even number.
>  Eliminate the numbers where the 2nd digit is 5, as multiplying by 5 will make the last digit either 5 or 0, and we already know the last digit can't be zero.

At this point,

> we really just need the last two digits. My idea was to multiply the reverse of the  last two digits, to get a 3-digit number. There are 44 2-digit numbers to check, which is somewhat trivial to verify, as there are at most 2 numbers, that when multiplied by  the last digit, will get the first digit as the final digit of the total.

The numbers, and divisors are:

> 713 / 31 = 23
>  819 / 91 = 9
>  924 / 42 = 22
>  328 / 82 = 4
>  962 / 26 = 37
>  972 / 27 = 36
>  679 / 97 = 7
>  384 / 48 = 8
>  294 / 49 = 6
>  295 / 59 = 5

Comment: Good answer and I've upvoted, but I wonder if there's a way of reducing the amount of case checking still further? Quite possibly there isn't, as I didn't have a solution in mind before posting, but intuitively it feels like modular arithmetic should help.

Comment: You missed one...

Comment: @DanielMathias found and added it.